# Добавить анимацию Загрузки в функцию

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-animation

Здравствуйте
мне нужно добавить анимацию загрузки в функцию которая срабатывает после того как кликнули на кнопку

вот сама функция

```
function get_revpopup_cart( product_id, action, quantity ) {
    quantity = typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1;
    if ( action == "catalog" ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + quantity,
            dataType: 'json',

        beforeSend: function(){
            $('body').addClass('blur2');
            $('#pagefader2').fadeIn(70);
        },
   .............
```

вот анимация загрузки <`div class="page_gif_progress_icon"><div class="circle"></div></div>`

кнопка: `<a onclick="get_revpopup_cart('103', 'catalog', '1');" data-toggle="tooltip" title="В корзину"><i class="fa fa-border fa-shopping-basket"><span class="prlistb">add in cart</span></i>`

анимация должна появиться перед `$('body').addClass('blur2');` и пропасть после того как функция будет выполнена

спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function get_revpopup_cart( product_id, action, quantity ) {
    quantity = typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1;
    if ( action == "catalog" ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + quantity,
            dataType: 'json',

        beforeSend: function(){

            $('body').append('<div class="page_gif_progress_icon"><div class="circle"></div></div>').addClass('blur2');
            $('#pagefader2').fadeIn(70);
        },
```

И в обработке результата добавить:

```
$(".page_gif_progress_icon").remove();
```

Comment: Прям то, что нужно! огромное спасибо!